# Does my level at time of reincarnation matter?

Tags: disgaea-5

I have never been fond of reincarnation in any Disgaea game, but I decided to do it in Disgaea 5.

It is my understanding that you keep the skills from your previous class, as well as stat bonuses from when you previously created this character. So every time you reincarnate, those stat bonuses will keep adding up.

I have a workflow that allows me to get 5000 mana to reincarnate Killia fairly quickly. Usually when he reaches level 150 or so.

My question is: does the level at time of reincarnation matter? What if I reincarnate Killia at level 150 instead of level 2000? If I reincarnate him at level 2000, do I get bigger benefits? Is there a limit to the times reincarnation would be useful?

Answer (score 3):

Summary:Levels banked over multiple Reincarnations, and the level BEFORE your last reincarnation are when it matters most.

Reincarnation has a handful of benefits, and while I havn't sat down and fully explored the exact mechanics in D5, it seems mostly similar to the previous titles

When leveling, the character will rise in stats by a Percentage of their existing stats. Thus an attack of 10 at level 1 vs. attack of 20 at level 1 could be the difference of millions at level 5000.

Reincarnation gives two bonus's to starting stats.
(Numbers are made up, but reflect the idea of what's happening)

1. Based on how high a given stat was at the time of reincarnation, it adds a flat bonus per stat to the following reincarnation. This does not carry over to subsequent ones, and is calculated per stat.
   Example : if Killia normally had 18 attack and 10 hit on character creation, and he was at 20 million attack and 6 million hit at level 3000, on reincarnation, he may have 32 attack and 18 hit (with attack receiving more of a boost due to the stat being higher then hit)
2. Every time you reincarnate, the levels are "Banked" for the character for a running total. Based on how many levels are banked, the amount of "bonus" assignable stats for that character increases.
   This does carry through multiple reincarnations, but does have a cap. The benefit to this is it lets you specialize where you'd like with your stats.

Sidenote : Skimming through reddit for some of the info, it looks like it's possible to max stats while completely sidestepping the reincarnation system
https://www.reddit.com/r/Disgaea/comments/3rdy8h/d5_maximum_total_reincarnation_level/
Though I'd still do it just for resetting Chara World entry costs (Mmm move speed)